# Sort according to last column

Tags: java, sorting

I have an array like that:

```
 UserID |ItemID | Score
    1      10     2.0
    1      11     1.2
    1      12     1.4
```

..........

I want to sort the array according to score column. My code is:

```
double[][] arr=new double [1000][3];

    int i=0;int j=0;int k=0;
    while ((phrase = br.readLine()) != null) {
         String[] splited =phrase.split("\t");
         arr[i][0]=Double.parseDouble(splited[0]);
         i++;
         arr[j][1]=Double.parseDouble(splited[1]);
         j++;
         arr[k][2]=Double.parseDouble(splited[2]);
         k++;
    }


    //print(a);
    System.out.println();
   Arrays.sort(arr, new java.util.Comparator<double[]>() {
       public int compare(double[] a, double[] b) {
            return (int)(a[1] -b[1]);
        }
    });
    print(arr);
```

But it does not work ! what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `a[2]` if you need to sort it by third column.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[][] arr = { { 1, 10, 2.0 }, { 1, 11, 1.2 }, { 1, 12, 1.4 }, };
    ;
    Arrays.sort(arr, new Comparator<double[]>() {
        public int compare(double[] o1, double[] o2) {
            return Double.compare(o1[2], o2[2]);
        }
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i][j]);
            System.out.print("\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Comment: Also  I use  return (int)(a[1] -b[1]); and does not sort the array but as you say I use this return : return Double.compare(o1[2], o2[2]);  it works .Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you want to sort by the *last* column you have to compare the *last* index in the second dimension, which is 2. Thus you should do `return (int)(a[2] -b[2]);` rather than `return (int)(a[1] -b[1]);`.

Btw, why are you using 3 indices `i`, `j` and `k`? Why don't you just use one, e.g. `i`?

*Edit*:

Rethinking the comparison, you should not use `(int)(a[2] -b[2])` but rather `Double.compare(a[2], b[2])` as suggested by @Prashant Bhate.

The reason is that if the difference between the two values is less then 1 or more than -1 the cast to `int` will result in 0, which means both are equal. Example: `(int)(0.5 - 1.4) = (int)(-0.9) = 0`.

Comment: @user951487 You are right, I added an explanation why Prashant Bhate's comparison works and why mine doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the score column is the 3rd column of the table - you are sorting on the second column - i.e.

```
    Arrays.sort(arr, new java.util.Comparator<double[]>() {
    public int compare(double[] a, double[] b) {
        return (int)(a[2] - b[2]);
    }
```